# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'U' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an "error converting varchar to int" for fields `Q1_c` and `Q2_c`.

Those fields are `CHAR(1)` and the values for those fields are either 1,2,3,4,5, or `U`, but it will not convert when there is a `U`, so I am trying to change the value of `U` to something else like 0. I have also tried `CAST(a.q2_c as varchar(1)) = 'U'` - but that doesn't work either. Should I be using `INT` or `VARCHAR()`? I have also tried using `CONVERT` instead of `CAST`.

```sql
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
as
select distinct
         IND.tb_cdcp_individuals as Individuals_IndividualID 
       , A.[tb_cdcp_individuals] as ATQInfant_IndividualID
       , A.CreateDate as ATQInfant_CreateDate
       , CAST(a.q1_c as varchar(3)) as A_Q1
       , CAST(a.q2_c as varchar(3)) as A_Q2
        ---Infant Sum
       , Sum(isnull(cast(a.Q1_c as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(a.Q2_c as int),0)) as InfantSum
        ---Change U to 0
       , case when CAST(a.q1_c as int) = 'U' then 0 else 0 end as Unknown1
       , case when CAST(a.q2_c as int) = 'U' then 0 else 0 end as Unknown2
from DBO.tb_cdcp_ATQInfant a
left join DBO.tb_cdcp_individuals ind on a.[tb_cdcp_individuals] = ind.[tb_cdcp_individuals]
where ind.agegroup_c = 'C' 
group by IND.tb_cdcp_individuals, A.tb_cdcp_individuals, A.CreateDate   
       ,     a.q1_c
       ,     a.q2_c
GO
```

Comment: Well `'U'` isn't a `int`, so how do you expect `CAST(a.q1_c as int)`, let alone `CAST(a.q1_c as int) = 'U'`, to work?

Comment: I'm not being rude, at all, the error and data is literally telling you to problem here. You're getting an error telling you that you `'U'` can't be converted to an `int`. You've told us you have a column, that your trying to convert to an `int` has the value `'1'`,`'2'`,`'3'`,`'4'`,`'5'`,`'U'`, and you're then trying to compare that converted `int` value to `'U'`; this would in effect mean you're trying to convert the ***letter*** `U` to an `int` twice. That is never going to work. `'U'` isn't a number.

Comment: @Dee could you paste some sample data please? in your query, I see a.q1_c (and a.Q2_c ) is casted to both varchar(3) and int. So, confused on kind of data that this column holds. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @sam As the second sentence of the question explains, *the values for those fields are either 1,2,3,4,5, or U*.

Comment: @Dee How about this: case when a.q1_c = 'U' then 0 else a.q1_c end as Unknown1

Comment: working example (remove spaces between @ and variable name as SO is not allowing without space)
declare @ q1_c char(1)
set @ q1_c = 'u'
select case when @ q1_c = 'u' then 0 else @ q1_c end --returns 0
set @ q1_c = '3'
select case when @ q1_c = 'u' then 0 else @ q1_c end  --returns 3

Comment: I'm not sure I can declare a variable in a SQL view.

Comment: @Dee you don't need to declare a variable. I just showed you can modify your case statement similar to above. Please wait, I am adding this as answer here and let us know whether that helps or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go about this in a couple of different ways:

Since the fields are in character format, replace 'u' with '0' and then convert it into int:

```
CAST(Replace(q1_c,'u','0') as int)
```

Or if you wanted to create a new calculated field you can directly create an integer field:

```
Case when q1_c='u' then 0 else CAST(q1_c as int) end as q1_c_calc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works if i comment out "Sum(isnull(cast(a.Q1_c as int),0)) + Sum(isnull(cast(a.Q2_c as int),0)) as InfantSum". So now not sure how to get the sum to work.

Comment: Actually I used the first part **CAST(Replace(q1_c,'u','0') as int)** for the InfantSum and the error goes away. I'll mark as answer if this works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea that occurs to me is to define another table ... with a `CHAR(1)` for every possible value, and an `INT` for the corresponding number.  Then, simply `JOIN` to that table.  No doubt the SQL engine will simply slurp the whole thing into memory if it only contains 5 rows.  If someday more values need to be encoded, it's easy to do this.

Comment: I like this idea, especially since it's always possible that more encoding will be necessary if there's already a "U" along side 1 to 5. It also removes the need to add cumbersome CAST or CASE statements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you cannot do anything else to clean the data that is stored in the tables or do anything to control the values being inserted in said tables you can use TRY_CONVERT or TRY_CAST. Both functions when return NULL if the CHAR(1) cannot convert to an INT. You just test for NULL that way you don't have to worry about any other rouge characters that may get accidentally inserted.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sample') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #sample
    END
GO
CREATE TABLE #sample
(
    q1_c  CHAR(1),
    q2_c  CHAR(1)
)
INSERT INTO #sample(q1_c , q2_c )
VALUES ('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5')
       ,('u','U'),('$','$'), ('#','#'), ('^','^'), ('&','&'), ('*','*'),
       ('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5')

SELECT CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(q1_c AS INT) IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE q1_c END A_Q1, 
       CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(INT, q2_c) IS NULL THEN '0' ELSE q2_c END A_Q2,
       SUM(TRY_CAST(q1_c AS INT)) sumQ1_c, SUM(TRY_CONVERT(INT, q2_c)) sumQ2_c
FROM #sample
GROUP BY q1_c, q2_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vCDCP_rptInfantImprove]
as
select distinct
         IND.tb_cdcp_individuals as Individuals_IndividualID 
       , A.[tb_cdcp_individuals] as ATQInfant_IndividualID
       , A.CreateDate as ATQInfant_CreateDate
       , CAST(a.q1_c as varchar(3)) as A_Q1
       , CAST(a.q2_c as varchar(3)) as A_Q2
        ---Infant Sum

       , Sum(isnull( case when a.Q1_c = 'U' then 0 else cast(a.Q1_c as int) end,  0 )) + Sum(isnull( case when a.Q2_c = 'U' then 0 else cast(a.Q2_c as int) end,  0 )) as InfantSum
        --- Remove cast here and not sure what goes in else part.
       , case when a.q1_c = 'U' then 0 else a.q1_c end as Unknown1
       , case when a.q2_c = 'U' then 0 else a.q2_c end as Unknown2
from DBO.tb_cdcp_ATQInfant a
left join DBO.tb_cdcp_individuals ind on a.[tb_cdcp_individuals] = ind.[tb_cdcp_individuals]
where ind.agegroup_c = 'C' 
group by IND.tb_cdcp_individuals, A.tb_cdcp_individuals, A.CreateDate   
       ,     a.q1_c
       ,     a.q2_c
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple reasons for this not to work:

First of all, you have to make sure the values that you are trying to cast are compatible with the type you are trying to cast into. CAST(a.q1_c as int) will work fine when the value is 1,2,3,4,5, but will fail when the value is 'U'. If you're sure that the values are 1,2,3,4,5, or U, you could use 'case'

```
CAST(case when a.q1_c = 'U' then 0 else a.q1_c end  as int) = 'U'
```

if not, ISNUMERIC() might work for this case.

Also CAST(a.q1_c as int) = 'U' what are you tryng to do here? Why not just a.q1_c = 'U' ?